# Wordpress: Display image attachments from child pages of a specific page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, foreach, wordpress-theming

I am trying to display all image attachments on the child pages of a specific parent page, i.e. all the pictures on Pages 10, 11 and 12.

```
Projects (Page ID: 5)
- Project 1 (Page ID: 10)
- Project 2 (Page ID: 11)
- Project 3 (Page ID: 12)
```

This is what I have so far, and it works to display all images on the site:

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => 0,
        'post_type'   => 'attachment', 
        'numberposts' => -1
    );

    $images = get_children( $args );

    if ( empty($images) ) {
        // no attachments here
    } else {
        foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
        }
    }

?>
```

However, if I add the post parent ID (5), nothing comes up:

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => 5,
        'post_type'   => 'attachment', 
        'numberposts' => -1
    );

    $images = get_children( $args );

    if ( empty($images) ) {
        // no attachments here
    } else {
        foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
        }
    }

?>
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think get_children() return objects from a single parent post or all (passing 0 as value).

You may try a nested foreach to get all post children first, then query attachment page by page. Here is an untested sample, but it gives you an idea:

```
<?php 

$subpages_args = array(
    'post_parent' => 5,
    'post_type'   => 'page', 
    'numberposts' => -1
);

$sub_pages = get_children( $subpages_args );

foreach( $sub_pages as $subpage_id => $sub_page) {

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => subpage_id,
        'post_type'   => 'attachment', 
        'numberposts' => -1
    );

    $images = get_children( $args );

    if ( empty($images) ) {
        // no attachments here
    } else {
        foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an SQL Query based solution. Copy following function in your theme's functions.php

```
function get_children_page_attachments($parent_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    // just a precautionary typecast and check 
    $parent_id = intval( $parent_id );
    if( empty($parent_id) ) return [];

    $query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} P WHERE post_type='attachment' AND P.post_parent IN (SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_parent={$parent_id} AND post_type='page' )";
    return $wpdb->get_results($query, 'ARRAY_A');
}
```

Once you have above function in your functions.php, then you can use it like this:

```
// for example the parent page id is 16
$image_ids = get_children_page_attachments(16);
foreach($image_ids as $image_id) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image($image_id['ID'], 'full');
}
```